# Don't know how to change to lowercase in this scenario

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js, commando

I am trying to use the discord.js `awaitMessages` method but it doesn't seem to work with uppercase letters because my possible answers (`triviacharacterslist.js`) are all lowercase. I tried to convert this (in the code) but it doesn't seem to work.

`triviachar.js`:

```
const iKF = Characters.KiritoVariants;
        const possibleAnswers = [iKF.kirito0, iKF.kirito1, iKF.kirito2, iKF.kirito3, iKF.kirito4, iKF.kirito5, iKF.kirito6, iKF.kirito7, iKF.kirito8];
        const triviaKiritoEmbed = new MessageEmbed()
            .setColor('#008fff')
            .setTitle(guessCharacterString)
            .setImage(Characters.CharacterImgs.kiritoimg)
    
        msg.channel.send(triviaKiritoEmbed)

        const filterK = m => possibleAnswers.some(answer => m.content.includes(answer));
        msg.channel.awaitMessages(filterK, { max: 1, time: 15000, errors: ['time'] })
        .then(collected => {switch(collected.first().content.toLowerCase()){
            case Characters.KiritoVariants.kirito0:
                msg.channel.send(fivePoint);
                break;
            case Characters.KiritoVariants.kirito3:
                msg.channel.send(fivePoint);
                break;
            case Characters.KiritoVariants.kirito6:
                msg.channel.send(fivePoint);
                break;
            case Characters.KiritoVariants.kirito1:
                msg.channel.send(tenPoint);
                break;
            case Characters.KiritoVariants.kirito2:
                msg.channel.send(tenPoint);
                break;
            case Characters.KiritoVariants.kirito4:
                msg.channel.send(tenPoint);
                break;
            case Characters.KiritoVariants.kirito5:
                msg.channel.send(tenPoint);
                break;
            case Characters.KiritoVariants.kirito7:
                msg.channel.send(tenPoint);
                break;
            case Characters.KiritoVariants.kirito8:
                msg.channel.send(tenPoint);
                break;
        }})
        .catch(collected => msg.channel.send('too bad u took too long ya 3am'));
    }
```

`triviacharacterslist.js`:

```
//character names ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

const KiritoVariants = {
    kirito0: 'kirito',
    kirito1: 'kirito sao',
    kirito2: 'kirito sword art online',
    kirito3: 'kazuto',
    kirito4: 'kazuto sao',
    kirito5: 'kazuto sword art online',
    kirito6: 'kazuto kirigaya',
    kirito7: 'kazuto kirigaya sao',
    kirito8: 'kazuto kirigaya sword art online'
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think [@Zsolt](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6126373/zsolt-meszaros) had the right idea but the execution is a bit wrong. Since all your answers are already in lowercase, calling `.toLowerCase()` on an answer string won't do much. Instead, you need to call `.toLowerCase()` on the string content. See the example below:

```js
const filterK = m => possibleAnswers.some(answer => m.content.toLowerCase().includes(answer));
```

Comment: I tried that but this happens https://imgur.com/SEdJeO8 https://imgur.com/ogjLjXp

Comment: In the second image you linked, I don't see the bot respond with the timeout message so my guess is that the `awaitMessage` does collect the message with the capital letter, but the `switch` case doesn't trigger correctly. Do you still have `switch (collected.first().content.toLowerCase())` in your code? You need `toLowerCase` for both the filter and the switch case

Comment: Oh sorry bud, I removed the one on the `switch` case, I put it back and now it works, thanks!

Comment: Oops, rookie mistake. Thanks for pointing it out. Have my upvote ;)

Answer (score 0):

The `includes()` method is case sensitive:

```js
const str1 = 'kirito sword art online'
const str2 = 'Kirito sword art online'

console.log(str1.includes(str2))
```

You can use `m.content.toLowerCase()` in your filter to convert the user's answer to lowercase:

```js
const filterK = m => possibleAnswers.some(answer => m.content.toLowerCase().includes(answer));
```

You could also simplify your switch statement and use `Object.values` to get an array of values in `possibleAnswers`:

```js
const possibleAnswers = Object.values(Characters.KiritoVariants);
const triviaKiritoEmbed = new MessageEmbed()
  .setColor('#008fff')
  .setTitle(guessCharacterString)
  .setImage(Characters.CharacterImgs.kiritoimg);

msg.channel.send(triviaKiritoEmbed);

const filterK = (m) =>
  possibleAnswers.some((answer) => m.content.toLowerCase().includes(answer));

msg.channel
  .awaitMessages(filterK, { max: 1, time: 15000, errors: ['time'] })
  .then((collected) => {
    switch (collected.first().content.toLowerCase()) {
      case Characters.KiritoVariants.kirito0:
      case Characters.KiritoVariants.kirito3:
      case Characters.KiritoVariants.kirito6:
        msg.channel.send(fivePoint);
        break;
      case Characters.KiritoVariants.kirito1:
      case Characters.KiritoVariants.kirito2:
      case Characters.KiritoVariants.kirito4:
      case Characters.KiritoVariants.kirito5:
      case Characters.KiritoVariants.kirito7:
      case Characters.KiritoVariants.kirito8:
        msg.channel.send(tenPoint);
        break;
    }
  })
  .catch((collected) => msg.channel.send('too bad u took too long ya 3am'));
```

Comment: I've tried it right now but unfortunately it didn't work, thanks for answer though.